# Batch File: How to delete files sort by date if there are subfolders in the folder?

Tags: batch-file

Here is one example:

There are 4 files:

```
C:\Test\1002.bak                  -- Created on Oct 2nd,2014
C:\Test\1009.bak                  -- Created on Oct 9th,2014
C:\Test\subfolder\1001.bak        -- Created on Oct 1st,2014
C:\Test\subfolder\1008.bak        -- Created on Oct 8th,2014
```

I want to a batch file to delete older files sorted by date, all files including subfolders.

It should be sorted like:

```
C:\Test\subfolder\1001.bak 
C:\Test\1002.bak                  
C:\Test\subfolder\1008.bak        
C:\Test\1009.bak
```

But if I run the below command, the result has been separated by subfolder.
For instance, "dir /a-d /od /s > result.txt"

result.txt:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is AADB-DB05

 Directory of c:\test

2014/10/02  11:40         4,220,416 1002.bak
2014/10/09  07:02     1,453,321,216 1009.bak
2014/10/09  18:44                 0 result.txt
               3 File(s)  1,457,541,632 bytes

 Directory of c:\test\subfolder

2014/10/01  10:51         4,220,416 1001.bak
2014/10/08  07:02     1,418,283,008 1008.bak
               2 File(s)  1,422,503,424 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               5 File(s)  2,880,045,056 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  35,598,852,096 bytes free
```

"dir /a-d /od /s /b> result.txt"

result.txt:

```
c:\test\1002.bak
c:\test\1009.bak
c:\test\result.txt
c:\test\subfolder\1001.bak
c:\test\subfolder\1008.bak
```

Is it possible to sort all files including all subfolders by date and then remove the older files when this folder disk size reach the limitation? thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
    set "targetFolder=%cd%"

    for /f "skip=4 tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%targetFolder%" "%targetFolder%" /l /nocopy /is /s /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts 
        ^| sort /R
    ') do echo del "%%b"
```

This code uses `robocopy` command (native in windows from Vista and later versions, available to download for previous versions) not copy files, but to get a list of the files with a timestamp in `yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss` format. This list is sorted in descending order (`sort /r`) and the first (newer) files in the list are skipped (`skip=4`). For the remaining elements in the list a `del` command is executed.

`del` operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command

Comment: @Binru, sorry, i think we are seeing it from different points of view. The code i've posted try to delete anything except the indicated number of newer files indicated in the `skip` clause. Is this what you need or are you searching to delete n number of old files?

Comment: Hi "MC ND", Thank you so much for your help and your solution. I removed the skip and it is working perfect as what I expect. Thanks again!